# Prove: if P=NP then there is polynomial reduction Clique to Path

Tags: complexity-theory, theory, reduction

Path = { (G,s,t) | G has directed path from s to t }

Clique= { (G,k) | G has k-clique}

I know by now that there is a polynomial reduction from Path to Clique without any assumption.
Why if P=NP then there is polynomial reduction in the opposite direction - from Clique to Path?
Thanks

Comment: this may help:http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-girl-who-proved-p-np/

Comment: The directed path problem or more formally, the s-t-connectivity problem is known to be NL-Complete.  That is, every problem in the class NL is reducible to the s-t-connectivity problem using non-deterministic log-space reductions.  So the claim being made is actually much stronger: it suggests that P = NP implies NL = NP.  Where is this statement suggested?